# Firefox 57 error on Gmail refresh: Oops… the system encountered a problem (#007)

Tags: firefox, gmail

Since the update to Mozilla Firefox 57, my (always open) Gmail tab continually hangs. the error I get is:

`Oops… the system encountered a problem (#007) - Retrying in xx:xx`

If I reload the page, it works, but the error always comes back after some time.  So I don't receive emails unless I manually do a page reload.

In my searches I've found others with the same issue that seem to be related to antivirus on Windows (Avast or AVG), but I'm not running antivirus.

I've tried clearing all Google cookies but no improvement.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Comment: No improvement so far.  I've tried disabling some extensions, but haven't had the time to go through all extensions one by one to test, especially since it's an intermittent issue.

Comment: Try starting Firefox in Safe Mode, [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode#w_how-to-start-firefox-in-safe-mode) is how, if you don't get that error message, we can assume the problem is with some extension, otherwise is Firefox itself, so you could try to re-install it.

Answer (score 1):

Disable all extensions and see if it still happens - If not, then enable them one by one until it reappears.

You haven't mentioned trying this, so I'm putting this out there as an answer. Can't comment in this forum, as of yet.